# Which sql server php extension for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, php

I'e been developing on my local wiindows 7 machine with sql server using the php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6 PHP extension.

I'm moving my application to the production server which diesn't have the extension yet. there is some documentation here but it doesn't say which version I need for Server 2008 R2 Standard. Threadsafe or non-threadsafe?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Does anyone know?

Thanks,
Jonesy

Answer (score 0):

Get the details of php installed in the server using php_info();

Try to find "Thread"

if the thread safe is enabled use according to it.

good luck.